# Show files starting with dot in VS Code Command bar

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do include files starting with a `.` like `.editorconfig` or `.gitlab-ci.yml` in the search results when using <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> in Visual Studio Code on macOS? They're shown in the Explorer window.

**Update**: They're not excluded in the `Search: Exclude` setting:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you haven't excluded them in the `Search: Exclude` setting (with a pattern like `**/.*`?  That is the only way I can remove them from the QuickOpen Panel.  I had to close and reopen vscode to get the ability to see those dot files again after I removed that setting.

Comment: No, updated the question

Comment: Did you checked your vscode **User** and **Workspace** settings? They are maybe different... (documentation: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)

Comment: Workspace and User don't differ here.